# How to read each row of grid

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use a tool tip on every row of a grid to show details whenever user place pointer on particular cell. It's supposed to show details for every row but it only shows details for the first row. Can any one help me?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "0" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text) || e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "&nbsp;")
    {
        e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

        dateSetExport.Tables.Clear();
        dateSetExport.Reset();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Startdate", gvDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Employe_Id", e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Split('-')[0]);
        DataTable dt1 = DataHelper.getDataTableExecuteSP("usp_GetToolTip", param);
        dt1.TableName = "ToolTip";
        dateSetExport.Tables.Add(dt1);
        string tooltip = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            tooltip = tooltip + dt1.Rows[j]["normal_working_hours"].ToString() + " Hours : " + dt1.Rows[j]["description"].ToString()+"\n\n";
        }
        e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = tooltip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which grid event are you creating the tooltips?

Comment: tooltip = tooltip + dt1.Rows[j]["normal_working_hours"].ToString() + " Hours : " + dt1.Rows[j]["description"].ToString()+"\n\n";   getting desciption along with hour

Answer (score 0):

You can use another foreach in order to loop all rows :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       //do your staff
   }
}
```

But for me, you should use GridView_RowDataBound event :

```
 protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
      {
        if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "0" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells  [i].Text) || e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "&nbsp;")
         {
    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
          }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

        dateSetExport.Tables.Clear();
        dateSetExport.Reset();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Startdate", gvDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Employe_Id", e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Split('-')[0]);
        DataTable dt1 = DataHelper.getDataTableExecuteSP("usp_GetToolTip", param);
        dt1.TableName = "ToolTip";
        dateSetExport.Tables.Add(dt1);
        string tooltip = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
        tooltip = tooltip + dt1.Rows[j]["normal_working_hours"].ToString() + " Hours : " + dt1.Rows[j]["description"].ToString()+"\n\n";
        }`enter code here`
        e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = tooltip;
       }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I am Using  RowDataBound event

Comment: Does it hit the event for every row or only once?

Comment: So, you should use the foreach GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows.